# Почему такая большая задержка при передаче?

Tags: python, arduino, serial

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться, почему нижеследующий код на python, работает только если задержка (**time.sleep(1)**) больше 1 секунды?

```
import time
import serial

ser = serial.Serial(port='/dev/ttyUSB0',baudrate=115200)
ser.write(b'1')
while 1:
    ser.write(b'test\n')
    time.sleep(1)
    while ser.inWaiting() > 0:
        line = ser.readline()
        if line:
            print(line.decode().strip())
```

Код скетча для Arduino UNO:

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
}

void loop() {

String incomingData;

if (Serial.available() > 0) {  //если есть доступные данные

       incomingData = Serial.readString();
       Serial.println("123456789");
    }
}
```

Comment: Попробуйте добавить `serial.flash()` после `serial.write(b'test')`.

Comment: к сожаление не помогло.

Comment: Arduino при подключении некоторое время ждет, когда в нее начну загружать скетч, и только после этого начнет принимать от вас команды. Поэтому после подключения необходимо подождать от 2 до 4 секунд. Либо сделать так, чтобы ардуино не ожидала загрузки скетча. Это делается аппаратно.

Comment: Вы были правы. Ардуина перезагружается и в начале нужна пауза. Переписал скетч и код на python: https://gist.github.com/nikitachukov/e4c3538c72ff7f269cf6e78aef85259d

Comment: https://gist.github.com/nikitachukov/7dbe0d6c1a2099181cd1603808a88c61 От задержек удалось избвится.

Comment: @НикитаЧуков, добавьте как ответ